# Signify for view to search for next task url

Tags: django-viewflow

I am asking if there is a prefered method of making `get_next_task_url()` redirect to the next process url. `get_next_task_url()` looks for `_continue` in `request.POST` however the POST object is not able to be modified.

Currently i am adding a hidden field into my form:

```
<input id="continue" type="hidden" name="_continue" value="true">
```

Is there a variable that i can set within the views or flow classes to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Viewflow is the thin workflow layer on top of usual django views.

As for usual django views, to set redirect url can redefine get_success_url in your code

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormMixin/#get_success_url